# How can I automatically change the display settings for dual monitors to "mirror" when a user logs out?

Tags: windows, batch-file, group-policy

I have an situation where users are using a projector as a second monitor (extended desktop where the projector is primary monitor) in classrooms. The issue arises when the user logs out, they do not switch the computer to primary monitor, or change the screen display settings back to mirror. The result is faculty not seeing a log in screen when attempting to log into our computers since the primary monitor is the projector.

I have thought of using a batch file using DisplaySwitch.exe /clone, this will change the display settings to mirror. Seeing as this script needs to be run on log out, I used Windows Group Policy to run on user log out. This isn't working for me, and after some investigation I believe it is because the batch file is unable to finish as Windows is terminating the script before completion. I could be wrong on the reasoning for it not working. I have also replicated the script in VBscript and PowerShell and wasn't able to get either to run on log out.

So, is there a way to automatically change the display settings on a Windows system to "mirror" or "duplicate" when a user logs out?

```
@echo off
title Script to mirror screen

echo Switching to mirror screen

DisplaySwitch.exe /clone
```

Comment: You could use a scheduled task that runs on user logout.